# iPad calculator app

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications

I need a scientific calculator for the iPad; preferably it shows the functions like a real scientific calculator i.e. when you press sin you get sin( on your "display" & not just the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SciCal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scical-scientific-calculator/id406922027?mt=8); it looks and feels like a real scientific calculator, it also plots graphs and has a lot of other features like calculation history and more. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDv8kkvU6rw) gives a good overview of this app.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest **PCalc** (the lite version is free) or **i41CX** (really good for hard-core fans of HP calculators)

Comment: I really like Pcalc.

Answer (score 0):

## TouchCalc

My favourite calculator app for iOS for some time. Functional, clean interface gets it done. The bit mode is great for algorithm writing with bit manipulations. I think this was one of the first apps I purchased when I got my first iPhone. Still use it daily.

It doesn't do quite what you want when  you hit `sin` but it does show you, below the answer, that the operation used to compute the answer was `sin`.

It's available via the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/touchcalc/id286091993?mt=8). And if it's not free, it's close to it.

Comment: With the whole sin thing I mean that I want the calculator for the iPad to work like a normal scientific calculator i.e. you press sine first & then enter the angle & not the other way round

Comment: Ah. You want infix style entry. No, TouchCalc does not have that. It's immediate execution style. sine(30) is entered as: `3` `0` `sin`

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://products.wolframalpha.com/ipad/) has an iPad app. It is admittedly $1.99 from the App Store, but not only will you get basic calculator features, but some pretty serious math and data reference chops in a small package.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill for your needs, but the granddaddy of scientific calculation on the iPad is MathStudio, formerly known as SpaceTime. Not just a scientific/graphing calculator, it's a very complete CAS (computer algebra system). And it does use the infix notation you prefer.